# Question about Bloch's Theorem : Exercise XII.1.2 from Functions of one complexe variable (John B. Conway)

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

**Bloch's Theorem.** Let $f$ be an analytic function on a region containing $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and satisfying $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$. Then there is a disk $S\subset \mathbb{D}$ on wich $f$ is one-one and such that $f(S)$ contains a disk of radius $\frac{1}{72}$.

Suppose that in the statement of Bloch's Theorem it is only assumed that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$. What conclusion can be drawn ?

(Hint: Consider the functions $f_{s}(z)=s^{-1}f(sz)$, $0<s<1$.)

Answer (score 0):

For every $s$, $f_s$ is defined and analytic on a disk $\mathbb{D}_s$ with radius $1/s$ (bigger than the unit disk), and it satisfies $f_s(0) = 0$ (obvious) and $f_s'(0)=1$ (apply chain rule). Then, every one of the $f_s$ verifies the hypothesis of Bloch's theorem, so they are injective on (maximal) disks $S_s$, with $f_s(S_s)$ containing a disk of radius $1/72$.

Since $f_s$ is injective for $z\in S_s$, then $f$ must be injective whenever $z$ is in $sS_s$, which is a smaller disk. You can see that the maximal disk $D$ of injectivity of $f$ determines all $S_s = \frac{1}{s}D$.

We know that $f_s(S_s)$ contains a disk of radius $1/72$, but $f_s(S_s) = f_s(\frac{1}{s}D) =\frac{1}{s}f(D)$. Since $\frac{1}{s}f(D)$ contains a disk of radius $1/72$ for all $s\in (0,1)$, we deduce that $f(D)$ contains also a disk of radius $1/72$.

We deduce that $f$ is one-to-one on a disk $D$ and that $f(D)$ contains a disk of radius $1/72$. That is, Bloch's theorem is still true.

Comment: I understand the begining but i think that we can't determine $D$ because every $S_{s}$ as is own center. Do you know how to avoid this problem ?